# Instantiating a widget layout on the lock screen Android

Tags: android, widget, locking, screen, lockscreen

I have seen the other posts about lock screen widgets. I know that 4.2 is the latest version to have lock screen API.

My problem is I've created an xml:

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="294dip"
    android:minHeight="72dip"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="0"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/keyguard"
    android:widgetCategory="keyguard">
</appwidget-provider>
```

and a layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/keyguard"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/appwidget"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/controls"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/control_play_pause"
                android:layout_width="100dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_media_play_dim"
                android:paddingTop="1dip"
                android:paddingBottom="1dip"
                android:scaleType="centerInside" />

            <ImageView
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_width="1dip"
                android:layout_height="20dip" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/control_stop"
                android:layout_width="100dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_media_stop_dim"
                android:paddingTop="1dip"
                android:paddingBottom="1dip"
                android:scaleType="centerInside" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

I'm not entirely clear on the provider (but I have made one and added it to AndroidManifest.xml) so any help would be appreciated. For now, I just want to make that layout display on the lock screen (just a simple media player control).

Thanks!

Comment: Media Player Control lock screen widget? Instead of or in addition to [RemoteControlClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RemoteControlClient.html) which already creates a widget for media playback control on the lock screen immediately?

Comment: Thanks. But the way I'm going to do this I will need a custom version. I'm not going to have foward or back and play will toggle to pause and a stop button.

Comment: You control exactly what buttons appear on a RemoteControlClient so that in and of itself isn't a deal breaker. Do note that a RemoteControlClient is required if you want to show music controls on Android Wear devices and lock screen widgets are not available on newer Samsung phones (such as the S5 - they are specifically disabled by Samsung) and not available at all on the current Android L developer preview.

Comment: My deepest apologies ianhanniballake. I was too hasty. I downloaded the RandomMusicPlayer demo and just discovered the buttons are controllable. I will look deeper into this but I do consider that your answer is sufficient for my needs.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need customizable media control buttons, you can use [RemoteControlClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RemoteControlClient.html) to automatically publish music controls to the lock screen. Controls can be customized by using the [RemoteControlClient.setTransportControlFlags](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RemoteControlClient.html#setTransportControlFlags(int)) method, passing in the flags associated with the buttons you want shown.

Comment: Ok, I've messed with .setTransportControlFlags and cannot seem to display a real stop button (square block) I've tried various flags but yet cannot get an actual stop button. RemoteControlClient.FLAG_KEY_MEDIA_STOP show the pause (double vertical line).